# AWS Cloudwatch Events publish topic not working :IOS silent push

Tags: amazon-web-services, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to send a silent push periodically by SNS. This is triggered by Cloudwatch events.
The push message goes out, but it is sent as raw text, and is not converted to silent push format by SNS. As you can see SNS topic publish works fine, and silent push goes out.
What am i doing wrong?
[image: SNS publish]

[image: Cloudwatch events]

[image: push]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't struggle with this, send it to a lambda function, where you can create the JSON request.

```
public String handle(JsonObject request, Context lambdaContext) throws 
BadRequestException, InternalErrorException {
    logger = lambdaContext.getLogger();
    Map<String, MessageAttributeValue> messageAttributes = new HashMap<>();
    AmazonSNSClient client = new AmazonSNSClient().withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1);

    PublishRequest rq = new PublishRequest();
    rq.setTopicArn(ENDPOINT_TOPIC);
    rq.setMessageStructure("json");
    rq.setMessage(getSilentAppleMessage());
    messageAttributes.put("AWS.SNS.MOBILE.APNS.TTL", new MessageAttributeValue().withDataType("String").withStringValue("120"));
    rq.setMessageAttributes(messageAttributes);
    client.publish(rq);
    GeneralResponse output = new GeneralResponse();
    output.setSuccess(true);
    return getGson().toJson(output, GeneralResponse.class);
}

public static String getSilentAppleMessage() {
    Map<String, Object> mainMessageMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    Map<String, Object> appleMessageMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    Map<String, Object> appMessageMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    appMessageMap.put("content-available", 1);
    appleMessageMap.put("aps", appMessageMap);
    mainMessageMap.put("default", "");
    mainMessageMap.put("APNS_SANDBOX", jsonify(appleMessageMap));

    logger.log(jsonify(mainMessageMap));
    return jsonify(mainMessageMap);
}

private static String jsonify(Object message) {
    try {
        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(message);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw (RuntimeException) e;
    }
}
```